# Byte array or image file for IOS Ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm working on an IOS ionic application and I need to display too many thumbnail images. Due to offline features, I also need them to store locally. So my question is, should I use byte array and save these in SQLite or just download the files and save in the application file[if it is possible]?

Which one is the better approach or are these the same? 
Any impact on caching or performance of the application?

Since this is my very first Hybrid application, I'm very new to these field. Please forgive me if this is a dumb question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ionic-cache-src](https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src) library for image cache.

You can cache image using this library as

```
<img alt="" cache-src="IMAGE_URL"/>
```

Comment: This is perfect solution! Thank you.